# Why is no default value generated/inserted?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, postgresql-9.6

I have just altered a table `place` and it's column `claimed` like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE place
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS claimed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false;
```

In phpPgAdmin I can see that it worked. Also all initial values are correctly set to `false`.

Howerver, as I create a new record:

```
this.placeRepository.save(place);
```

I am getting:

```
ERROR: null value in column "claimed" violates not-null constraint
```

or as a whole:

```
2018-09-21 21:56:47.902  WARN 30087 --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
2018-09-21 21:56:47.903 ERROR 30087 --- [nio-8443-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: null value in column "claimed" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (17, 2018-09-21 19:56:47.885, 2018-09-21 19:56:47.885, ChIJj15CRtukokcRcvSmyJCKGU4, 49.7759560000000008, 9.57715980000000044, Wertheim Village, Almosenberg, Wertheim, null).
2018-09-21 21:56:47.908  INFO 30087 --- [nio-8443-exec-9] m.a.s.e.CustomRestExceptionHandler       : org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException
2018-09-21 21:56:47.908  INFO 30087 --- [nio-8443-exec-9] m.a.s.e.CustomRestExceptionHandler       : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException
```

I don't see what's the problem here. So why is the default value not generated here? It seems to me Hibernate just tries to insert a `null` value?

I think this should not matter but just to be sure I also added `nullable = false` in my Java code to the column of the entity class:

```
@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean claimed;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is :

1. Just setting a default value for the field

   `@Column(nullable = false)
   private Boolean claimed = true;`

---

2. Setting default value in case if the value is not set

   `@PrePersist
   public void prePersist() {
       if(claimed == null)
           claimed = true;
   }`

---

3. Use columnDefinition

   `@Column(columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 1")
   private Boolean claimed;`